# Download the chromedriver using the API in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

We have an Python automation solution where we are using the chrome browser.

Using the below code to create the chrome object:

driver = webdeiver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

The problem is if the chrome browser is updated we need to replace the same version of chromedriver.

To download it, we used the below api to download the chromedriver zip file.

[https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/{version}/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/%7Bversion%7D/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip)

Since our chrome browser version is 177.0.5938.149, we are using the chrome for testing api.

However this version is not existing in the testing lab also in the latest release api.

Where do I get this particular version using the web api?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package webdriver_manager

> pip install webdriver_manager

ChromeDriverManager() accepts a version as an argument

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
version = "177.0"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version=version).install()),options=option)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: Getting the following error after executing the install code. "There is no such url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/117.0.5938.149/chromedriver_win32.zip